# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused")

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lampp

hello guys i have been trying to fix this problem for about 3 hours and can't fix it i want to start mysql in lampp

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

and this is what i got

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (111 "Connection refused")
```

i dont have mysql server installed and i cant even get into localhost/phpmyadmin as well someone please help me im stuck :(
if you want some specific detail just comment below :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you're trying to connect to a locally running MySQL server,... but your questions then states that you don't have MySQL server installed.

Comment: @NicolaWorthington yeah i meant i dont have mysql server installed directly on ubuntu but im using the one that provided by lampp so if i wanna start mysql i type /opt/lampp/bin/mysql instead of typing mysql directly from terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to local `MySQL` server, you need to have it installed and running in the first place. Lamp will try to connect to existing (running) MySQL server but it won't start a server on it's own.

Here are the instructions to [install](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/installing.html) and [start](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/automatic-start.html) MySQL server (locally). Once it's up and running, you can connect to it, e.g. with php:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);
```

**Update**

If you are running an instance provided by Lamp image then you can check the status by executing `service mysqld status` command and `start` it if it's not running. Have a look at [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-access-mysql-instance-created-by-lamp-image-when-creating-droplet) article for troubleshooting.